# Unable to create referenced entities using morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I've got the following object hierarchy:

```
class A {
    @Id private String id;
    ...
    @Reference private Set<B> setOfBs = ...
    ...
}

class B {
    @Id private String id = ...
    ...
    @Reference private Set<C> setOfCs = ...
    ...
}

class C {
    @Id private String id = ...
    ...
}
```

When I use Morphia (version 1.0.0-rc0) to save entities of type A, I see the following JSON in collection "A":

```
{
    "_id" : "CQ8RbtCINf", 
    "setOfBs" : [ 
        DBRef("setOfBs", "9JZ5OnNBZD"), 
        DBRef("setOfBs", "aDPHCe01Ti") 
    ]
}
```

The above structure looks good but I cannot find collections for objects of type B nor C. I only see the collection for A.

I can solve this problem by "dissecting" the A object, save the C objects first, then their parent B objects and then the A object. Not sure if this is the correct way to do it or if I'm mis-using Morphia.

As extra info, here's my datastore initialization code:

```
Morphia morphia = new Morphia();
morphia.mapPackage("com.company.application.model");
Datastore datastore = morphia.createDatastore(mongoClient, mongoDB);
datastore.ensureIndexes();
datastore.ensureCaps();
```

Comment: As Morphia wiki says, `@Reference will not save objects, just a reference to them; You must save them yourself.` So, you need to save them first [https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki)

Comment: And a word of caution: if A has 5 Bs and each B has 5 Cs, fetching A will result in 1+5+25 queries. Maybe embedding is more suitable, otherwise I'd be careful with any set, list, or map of references.

Comment: The issue I have with embedding is that while inserts/updates are rare, finding/filtering need to be very performant and will be 95% of the operations that the app will handle. Embedded entities in that case could prevent fast lookups/filtering.